# Android: Extra spacing in collapsed notification

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, notifications

I am making a persistent notification with a collapsed and expanded view. But my collapsed view is taking extra space at the bottom. It is not a layout issue I figured it out.

Initially, I have created a separated layout for the expanded and collapsed view but I realized that I need default design for the notification header, so I removed the collapsed view layout.

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_fix_icon)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomBigContentView(remoteExpandedViews)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
```

Please find below the layout file, which I have used for the expanded notification view. I don't use any layout for collapsed view. I want a title, description and two buttons in my expanded notification. From two buttons click, I am opening the activities directly.

removeExpandedViews.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_relativelayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info"
            android:text="Today's task"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotomedium"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_next_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next_icon"
            android:tint="@color/black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No task for today !"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_next_icon"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotomedium"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_title"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_relativelayout1"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_add_task"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Task"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorTitle"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_setting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Setting"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custome_expanded_notification_add_task"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorTitle"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: ic_fix_icon]

I want like any.do collapsed view.
[image: I want to make collapsed notification just like anydo]

Comment: Use uiautomatorviewer to check the UI hierarchy and see what's the additional view it's been inflating for your notification.

Comment: Hello, could you please also paste your `ic_fix_icon` and `remoteExpandedViews`?

Comment: @ravi Please Check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, it will definitely work.

```
NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: We get an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid importance level

Answer (score 0):

I see that your notification small icon is 77*77 px. According to android guidelines on notification small icon, thy should be no more than 24*24 px.

Also do consider less nesting for your custom layout. :)

Could you change the size and use it. Let me know if this does not work for you.

**Edit:**

Use the Image Asset from Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: I am using 24X24 icon only, and it still shows extra spacing.

Comment: Did you use the Add image asset from Android Studio and set the icon type to Notification?

Comment: Yes. I did exactly the same.

Comment: Last thing, you did not call `setCustomContentView(RemoteViews remoteViews)` on your `Builder`. Is that intended? Generally with Custom Big Content View, a Custom Content VIew is used too. Don't you want any minimized view for your notification. Try and add `setCustomContentView(null)` on your builder if you do not want any minimized view, or add a custom layout and pass it to the same.